# CiviRules Issue with Smart Groups

Tags: civicontribute, contacts, civireport, smartgroups, civirules

I am trying to use CiviRules to give a membership to contacts automatically when a contribution is added. I have a Membership smart group to filter members and non-members but getting an error when the rule is running when a contribution is entered. See attachments. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Drupal version 7.59, CiviCRM version 5.3 and CiviRules version 2.1

[image]
[image]

Comment: So someone becomes a member if they give over $100 for example, but not if they only give $80?

Comment: In a sense, yes. There is a rule to create new membership and one to renew a current membership.

Comment: right. i was just trying to get a sense of why core civimember couldn't do what was required

Comment: The action 'Add ... membership to a contact' is not present in CiviRules. Is this a custom developed action? Could it be that this action is causing the error?

Answer (score 1):

It is an error to do with the menu configuration. It should definitely not be there it will not stop CiviRules from executing your action. So the error lies somewhere else.

Comment: You have any idea how to fix the error? It looks like it is effecting CiviRules somehow though. Entering a $30 donation gives a membership, but then entering another $30 donation gives another membership. Which should not happen because I have the condition to filter out the Membership Smart group.

Comment: That error would not be caused by the one displaying in your earlier message. I would not expect fixing the menu error will fix your membership problem. The menu error will be fixed whenever there is funding, either from a customer or from ourselves.